# How to fetch all the records for last 6 months based on id from an entity along with all the entity mappings defined in main entity in spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, hibernate-mapping

I want to fetch all the data of last 6 months for a particular id in AlphaEntity including for all of the entities for which mapping is defined in the entity itself, i.e., sigma, epsilon, zeta and theta as well.

I am using spring boot 3.0.6 with java 17 and hibernate 6

The following are the different entities in my application:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ALPHA")
public class AlphaEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "alpha_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = 'profession')
    private String profession;

    @OneToOne
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @JoinColumn(name = "sigma_ref", referencedColumnName = "r_id")
    private ReferenceEntity sigma;

    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @OneToMany (cascade CascadeType.ALL, fetch FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns(value = {@JoinColumn(name = "beta_id", referencedColumnName = "beta_id"), 
                    @JoinColumn(name = "gamma_id", referencedColumnName "gamma_id")})
    private List<EpsilonEntity> epsilon;

    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @OneToOne (cascade CascadeType.ALL, fetch FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "gamma_ID", referencedColumnName="gamma_ID") 
    private ZetaEntity zeta;

    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @OneToMany (cascade CascadeType.ALL, fetch FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns(value = {
        @JoinColumn(name "delta_id", referencedColumnName = "delta_id"),
        @JoinColumn(name "gamma_id", referencedColumnName = "gamma_id")})
    private List<ThetaEntity> theta;
}
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "REFERENCE")
public class ReferenceEntity{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "r_id")
    private int rId;
    
    @Column(name = "r_desc")
    private int rDesc;
    
}
-
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EPSILON")
public class EpsilonEntity{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "epsilon_id")
    private int epsilonId;
    
    @Column(name = "beta_id")
    private int betaId;

    @Column(name = "gamma_id")
    private int gammaId;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;
    
}
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ZETA")
public class ZetaEntity{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "gamma_id")
    private int zetaId;
    
    @Column(name = "pet_name")
    private int petName;
    
}
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "THETA")
public class ThetaEntity{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "theta_id")
    private int thetaId;

    @Column(name = "gamma_id")
    private int gammaId;

    @Column(name = "delta_id")
    private int deltaId;
    
    @Column(name = "address")
    private String addr;
    
}
```

I tried doing so by creating the following interface and calling the `findLastSixMonthsData()` method from the service layer:

```
public interface AlphaRepository extends JpaRepository<AlphaEntity,Long> {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM ALPHA al WHERE al.blit_id = :id and al.chg_dttm >= :sixMonthsAgoDate", nativeQuuery = true)
    List<AlphaEntity> findLastSixMonthsData(@Param("id") Long id, @Param("sixMonthsAgoDate") LocalDateTime sixMonthsAgoDate)

}
```

But, in doing so, I am getting error - "Invalid column name r_id"

I am expecting to get all the data successfully in the entity which I will further map to the corresponding DTO classes. Currently, there are 26 records in the table ALPHA which matches the query criteria.

Please help me out to fetch this data such that Hibernate fires the minimum number of queries internally. Any other ways of completing the functionality is also appreciated :)